# Applet will work in IE, but not firefox

Tags: java, internet-explorer, firefox, applet

So I have created an applet that creates a file on the local hard drive, and eventually uploads it to a CGI that I have created.

When run on IE, the applet works fine, and creates and uploads the file properly.
However, on firefox, I get an error on the Java Console, access denied, showing me that it simply can't create the file. I created the certificate myself, and did not buy one or have it verified through a company.

I need a solution that will work for anybody who potentially uses the applet, meaning the fix can't just be editing my own settings, unless I can do that with every computer that accepts the certificate.

Answer (score 3):

Unsigned applets cannot access local disk on all browsers. It worked for you in IE because I believe that you ran it from file system (not via http). So, the right solution is not to create file on disk. Create content in memory and upload it. But remember: you can connect only to server the applet was downloaded from.

If you really have to create local file you have to sign the applet.

Answer (score 0):

May be, some `setting` has to be done. One of the reason could be your Mozilla Firefox is not java enabled.
Check the following links :

- [A fix for Java applets not loading in Firefox](http://www.techspot.com/blog/596/a-fix-for-java-applets-not-loading-in-firefox/)
- [Applet loads but hidden in Firefox](http://x10hosting.com/forums/programming-help/108093-applet-loads-but-hidden-firefox.html)

To test whether java is enabled or not in a web browser, click [**[here]**](http://javatester.org/enabled.html)

Answer (score 0):

[This bug](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=626362) may be relevant.

It states that Firefox kills java applets that take too long to load.  I have an example that works fine when loaded from a local resource but fails when it is remote.  Sometimes, reopening the applet can make it work as it appears that it loads more and more of the classes each time.